# jQuery Mobile page not showing up on mobile devices

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jplayer

I've got some problem, and I'm not sure that what it is from maybe jQuery Mobile or jPlayer.

I tried to open this page: http://music.x7dtv.com/m/radio/cool93

It works normally on desktop (Chrome) but when I tried it on mobile (iOS and Android); It shows the blank page. The other pages (http://music.x7dtv.com/m/radio) work fine except the page I included jPlayer.

The jPlayer Core seems fine here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://ip:8000/;stream/1"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        supplied:"mp3"
    });
});
```

EDIT: The response code is 200.

Comment: Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: I'm not sure, It works perfectly on Chrome. But you don't have any debugger in iOS or Android.

Comment: I know. Try placing some `alert(...)` statements in various places to see where the code gets. Perhaps at the beginning of each major function and let us know how you get on.

Comment: I tried commenting out the jPlayer `<script>` tag and it works, the page shows up. But jPlayer won't work anymore.

Comment: What is reasonable. What about commenting out any individual lines of jPlayer related code you have written?

Comment: The jPlayer Core seems fine, My code is on the question. I tried JSlint, there's no syntax error.

Comment: Sorry. I meant commenting out lines of your code to where the error is. It is unlikely to be a syntax error, but rather a runtime error of some sort.

Comment: I got it working now, instead of loading it with src, I directly put the script on that page. And that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED:

It was in my code which I included via `src` of `<script>` tag.